# Less css, nested attributes, :hover::after

Tags: css, nested, less

Is it possible to do this with less?

```
a {
    &:after {
        background: red;
    }
    &:hover {
        &:after {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get the `:after` to change color when hovering over `a`?

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: This definitely works

Comment: ... assuming the OP actually generated the pseudo-element with `content` in the first place, which is missing from the question.

Comment: Bah, my misstake, I had missed an ";" in my class. Therefore it didn't work.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following works fine for me:

```
a {
    &:after {
        content:'a';
        background: red;
    }
    &:hover {
        &:after {
            background: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

My LESS-enabled editor, compiled that to:

```
a:after {
  content: 'a';
  background: red;
}
a:hover:after {
  background: blue;
}
```

Which does work.

Answer (score 0):

> This is also work fine for me : -

```
 a{
    &:after{
        background: red;
        content: "Hover Text"
    }
    &:hover{
        &:after{
            background: yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

> And My terminal Compile that to:-

```
a:after {
  background: red;
  content: "Hover Text";
}
a:hover:after {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
a {

  &:after {

     background: red;

  }

  &:hover,
  &:after {

     background: blue;

  }

}
```

This is okay now :P